# Run ovun.sample in R doParallel foreach loop

Tags: r, doparallel

I just can not get working ovun.sample in the parallel foreach.

Below is the minimal workin example.

```
library(doParallel)
library(ROSE) # ovun.sample

if(!getDoParRegistered()){
  registerDoParallel(cores=detectCores())
}

foreach(i=1:2,.combine=rbind, .packages=c("ROSE")) %dopar% {
  my_data = iris[iris$Species != "setosa",]
  under_data <- ovun.sample(Species ~ ., data=my_data, N=40, seed = 1)$data
}
print(r)
```

I get error:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'my_data' not found"
```

Any ideas what did I miss. Or maybe some another over/under sampling package similar to ROSE that works with doParallel? Running on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `ovun.sample` is that it seems that unfortunately it attempts to execute the code assuming the variables will be in the global scope:
https://github.com/cran/ROSE/blob/master/R/data_balancing_funcs.R#L26

The following code helps to visualize why `ovun.sample` does not work:

```
my.ovun.sample <- function(dataset) {
  my_data <- dataset
  ovun.sample(cls ~ ., data = my_data, method="both", N=200, seed=1)$data
}

my.ovun.sample(dataset=hacide.train)
```

It will produce:

> Error in adj.formula(formula, data) : object 'my_data' not found

So, if we debug the problem, when it is executing line 24 in [ovun.sample source code](https://github.com/cran/ROSE/blob/master/R/data_balancing_funcs.R#L24):

```
sys.nframe()
# [1] 2
```

This means that R is currently in the [environment #2](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sys.parent.html).

And then we proceed to debug what variables are available in the current scope:

```
ls(sys.frame(2))
# [1] "Call"      "Call1"     "data"      "formula"   "m"         "method"    "N"         "na.action" "p"         "seed"     
# [11] "subset"
```

Then we proceed to debug what's inside the parent scope (which would be `my.ovun.sample` function):

```
ls(sys.frame(1))
# [1] "dataset" "my_data"
```

And finally in the global scope:

```
ls(sys.frame(0))
# [1] "hacide.test"    "hacide.train"   "my.ovun.sample"
```

Now, when the following line is executed:

```
res <- eval(Call1)
```

The code will throw an error because `my_data` is not available inside that environment. The code will work if we change it to:

```
my.ovun.sample <- function(dataset) {
  my_data <- dataset
  ovun.sample(cls ~ ., data = get("my_data", sys.frame(1)), method="both", N=200, seed=1)$data
}
```

Now, when working with `foreach`, the problem with `data=get("my_data", sys.frame(1))` is that that the parallel environment will not always be 1. To fix this, we need to work with a more generic way to send the current frame. This is a code that appears to work:

```
library(doParallel)
library(ROSE) # ovun.sample
data(hacide)

if (!getDoParRegistered()) {
  registerDoParallel(cores=detectCores())
}

my_results = foreach(i=1:2, .combine=rbind, .packages=c("ROSE")) %dopar% {
  my_data <- hacide.train
  my_data$i <- i

  # this sends the current_frame to global environment
  curr_frame <<- sys.nframe()

  ovun.sample(cls ~ ., data = get("my_data", sys.frame(curr_frame)), method="both", N=200, seed=1)$data
}

registerDoSEQ()

print(head(my_results))
#  cls          x1         x2 i
# 1   0  0.56444509 -0.7198744 1
# 2   0  0.73493507  0.4791222 1
# 3   0 -0.39307673  0.8098423 1
# 4   0 -0.39934508 -0.2746103 1
# 5   0 -0.06157228 -1.2983649 1
# 6   0  0.20251246 -0.6173485 1

print(tail(my_results))
#    cls        x1        x2 i
# 395   1 -2.789707 -1.497824 2
# 396   1 -2.149788 -1.708764 2
# 397   1 -0.741708 -1.973571 2
# 398   1 -2.149788 -1.708764 2
# 399   1 -1.427158 -1.415405 2
# 400   1 -2.037152 -1.127303 2

print(table(my_results$cls))
#   0   1 
# 196 204

print(table(my_results$i))
#  1   2 
# 200 200
```

Comment: Yes, this requires to have var global. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loop has a different environmental context for where it looks for `my_data`.  Try replacing `data=my_data` with `data=get("my_data", sys.frame(1))`.

Another approach is to set the data variable before the `foreach` and use the `.export=my_data` options in the `foreach` call to ensure that the data is pushed to each core before execution.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but `data=get("my_data", sys.frame(1))` does not work either. I also tried .export=c("my_data"), and also does not work. 

But this works:
`result <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=rbind, .packages=c("SDR", "ROSE") ) %dopar% {
  my_data = iris[iris$Species != "setosa",]
  sum(iris$Species == "virginica")
}

print(result)`

I just do not know why does not work with function ovun.sample.

Comment: For `.export=my_data` to work, `my_data` has to be defined before the `foreach` loop in the main code. That really should work.

It has to be about the execution environment.  `?ovun.sample` describes the `data` option as `If not specified, the variables are taken from “environment(formula).`.  That suggests to me that it could be a conflict between `.` in the formula and `my_data`.  What happens if you drop the `data=my_data` option entirely?

Answer (score 0):

when setting `my_data` within foreach loop, try using `my_data <<- ...`

this puts the results of the assignment into the global environment